# Transpiling TypeScript to Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I am creating a Node Project with Typescript and I have set the **target** option to **es6** in `tsconfig.json`

Node version 8 supports the `async/await` syntax but Typescript converts that to a generator function

How can I tell typescript not to convert es6 features already present in Node?

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10768 ?

Comment: Async/await *isn't* an ES6 feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

async/await is supported in ES2017, so u may need to set your target in tsconfig.json to ES2017.

P.S. You may find [meseret](https://github.com/kaleabmelkie/meseret) an interesting library to work with, if you're into TypeScript, async/await and Node.